# Dynamic form field cause loose focus on input while typing text on Ionic Framework

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm working in a dynamic form where it's possible to add some field dynamically. The structure of the form is:

```
FormGroup -> FormArray -> FormGroup
```

Pratically speaking the structure is

```
Groups -> [0...,n] -> Value -> [0...,n]
```

The problem is that every time I type some text on the dynamic input, Ionic seem to start the Digest process which destroy and recreate the DOM object.

In this specific case because input are generated dynamically with a *ngFor I loose the focus of the object and I can no longer enter text unless I click again on the input and type another character.

Same behavior happen if I click on the generated input and I resize the browser window. Component loose focus and I cannot type text anymore.

**The thing not happend for all component Input that are not dynamically generated.**

Look at the code below:

```
<!-- component.html -->

<form [formGroup]="componentiForm">
    <ion-list>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="floating">Codice</ion-label>
            <ion-input formControlName="codiceImpianto" type="text" placeholder="Codice impianto"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <!-- HERE OTHER INPUT -->

        <div formArrayName="gruppi">
            <h4>Componenti
                <ion-button size="small" (click)="addGruppo()">
                    <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
                </ion-button>
            </h4>
            <div class="box-valori" *ngFor="let gruppo of componentiForm.get('gruppi').value ;index as i"
                 [formGroupName]="i">
                <h5>Componente {{i}}</h5>
                <button (click)="addValore(i)"> Aggiungi valori</button>
                <!--                    <ion-button size="small" (click)="addValore(i)">-->
                <!--                        <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>-->
                <!--                    </ion-button>-->
                <div formArrayName="valori">
                    <h3>Parametri del componente</h3>

                    <div class="box-valori"
                         *ngFor="let valore of componentiForm.controls.gruppi['controls'][i].get('valori').value ;index as j">
                        <ion-list [formGroupName]="j">
                            <ion-item>
                                <ion-label position="floating">Nome Parametro*</ion-label>
                                <ion-input formControlName="key" type="text"
                                           placeholder="Nome Parametro"></ion-input>
                            </ion-item>
                            <ion-item>
                                <ion-label position="floating">Valore*</ion-label>
                                <ion-input formControlName="val" type="text" placeholder="Valore"></ion-input>
                            </ion-item>
                        </ion-list>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-list>
</form>
```

The component.ts is defined below

```
// other component code

componentiForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
        this.componentiForm = this.fb.group({
            codiceImpianto: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
            ......
            gruppi: this.fb.array([])
        });
}

addGruppo(): void {
        (this.componentiForm.get('gruppi') as FormArray).push(
            this.fb.group({valori: this.fb.array([])})
        );
}

addValore(groupId): void {

        const kv: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
            key: new FormControl('', {validators: Validators.required}),
            val: new FormControl('', {validators: Validators.required})
        });

        ((this.componentiForm.get('gruppi') as FormArray).at(groupId).get('valori') as FormArray).push(kv);
        console.log('Valori della form', this.componentiForm.get('gruppi'));
 }
 // other component code
```

I would like to avoid to create a variable without binding the formControlName which contain the form values .... It's seem to be a very bad solution..

Any solution to avoid this? Am I doing something wrong? Could it be a bug?

I'm using Ionic ver: 5.4.14

Comment: you need loop over "controls", not over "value", that's componentiForm.get('gruppi').value must be componentiForm.get('gruppi'). **controls** and componentiForm.controls.gruppi['controls'][i].get('valori').value must be componentiForm.controls.gruppi['controls'][i].get('valori'). **controls**

Comment: Ok Thank you.. it work! but pratically what is the difference?

Comment: "index as j" should be "j as index" in your *ngFor

Comment: @LucaT, when you iterate over "value" you has a problem: the "value" change when you change the input. At each change, Angular "redraw", and this is the reason becaouse you feel that you loose the focus. if iterate over "controls", controls not change -is an object-, is the "value"  property of the control witch change

Comment: @Eliseo Thank you! Yes It's clear! I think anyway is something about Ionic... I did something similar in pure angular but was working! Thank you again.